# How to send notification of CodePipeline status?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I have a couple of CD pipelines on AWS that do the following:

- listen for pushes to a Github repo
- build Docker images
- push the images to ECR
- Update ECS task definitions
- Update ECS services with CloudFormation stacks

I'd like to send notifications for:
- whenever the pipeline completes successfully
- if the pipeline fails, what step it failed on and why

I'm sure this is possible with SNS, but I couldn't find how to do it. Can anyone point me to resources on how to set up these kinds of notifications?

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline emits CloudWatch events on pipeline state changes (such as a pipeline succeeding or failing): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html

That will tell you when, although the notification may not tell you exactly why.

You could consume the event via a Lambda function which also looks up extra data (eg. CodeBuild logs) then adds them to an email notification to add the "why".